# How can I display all the Security Groups and members of those Groups from Active Directory in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

What I need to achieve is to display all the security groups in Active Directory with the members of each of those groups in my `GridView`

So for the most part I have got it to display the Security Groups with no problem.  It displays it like this (which is what I want):

```
| Groups     |
--------------
| Group 1    |
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to display the groups and their members so that it can look like this (not exactly but if possible in this format)

```
| Groups     |  Members   |
---------------------------
| Group 1    |  User 1    |
|            |  User 2    |
|            |  User 3    |
| Group 2    |  User 1    |
|            |  User 2    |
```

Would that be possible?

Here is the code I have for now:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);

GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, strADPath);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn col = new DataColumn(); 
col = new DataColumn("Security Groups");
dt.Columns.Add(col);

col = new DataColumn("Members");
dt.Columns.Add(col);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    dr["Security Groups"] = found.Name;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

    grdSecurityGroups.DataSource = dt;
    grdSecurityGroups.DataBind();

    ViewState["dirState"] = dt;
    ViewState["sortdr"] = "Desc";

    lblSecurityTotal.Text = grdSecurityGroups.Rows.Count.ToString();

    using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, strADPath))
    {
        if (group != null)
        {
            var usersPrincipals = group.GetMembers(true);

            foreach (UserPrincipal user in usersPrincipals)
            {
                dr["Members"] = user.Name;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

                grdSecurityGroups.DataSource = dt;
                grdSecurityGroups.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above shows the groups, but not the members of each of those groups.

I need some assistance here with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out and got it working The only problem I have now is to show the columns like this:

```
 | Groups     |  Members   |
 ---------------------------
 | Group 1    |  User 1    |
 |            |  User 2    |
 |            |  User 3    |
 | Group 2    |  User 1    |
 |            |  User 2    |
```

Instead of this:

```
 | Groups     |  Members   |
 ---------------------------
 | Group 1    |  User 1    |
 | Group 1    |  User 2    |
 | Group 1    |  User 3    |
 | Group 2    |  User 1    |
 | Group 2    |  User 2    |
```

Here is the working code however to display the groups and members in those groups:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);
            GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
            PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);
            GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, strADPath);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn(); 
            col = new DataColumn("Security Groups");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            col = new DataColumn("Members");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
            {
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.ToString());
                if (group != null)
                {
                    foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
                    {
                        dr["Security Groups"] = found.Name;
                        dr["Members"] = p.DisplayName;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                        grdSecurityGroups.DataSource = dt;
                        grdSecurityGroups.DataBind();
                        ViewState["dirState"] = dt;
                        ViewState["sortdr"] = "Desc";
                        lblSecurityTotal.Text = grdSecurityGroups.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    }
                    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (dt.Rows[i]["Members"].ToString() == "")
                            dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
```